# Local variable 'k1' value is not used

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

i am trying to build a simple menu with some conditions in it but i kept getting the error "Local variable 'k1' value is not used" at the used lines. I tried changing it to global but nothing happens.

```
def menu():

    print(" 1.Köşelerde ve Boyut Ortalarında Ast/8 kadar donatı \n 2. Köşelerde Ast/3, Boyut Ortalarında "
          "Ast/16 kadar donatı, \n 3.Karşılıklı Ast/2 kadar donatu \n 4.Tüm boyutlarda Ast/4 kadar donatı"
          "\n 5.Köşelere eşit dağılmış olarak k1=1")
    choice = input()

    if choice == "1":
        print("Asst/8 seçtiniz")
        if n > 1:
            k1 = 1.08
        else:
            k1 = 1.07 + 1.349*n - 3.994*n*n + 4.062*n*n*n - 1.406*n*n*n*n

    elif choice == "2":
        print("Ast/3 seçtiniz")
        if n > 1:
            k1 = 1.025
        else:
            k1 = 1.028 + 0.633*n - 1.868*n*n + 1.816*n*n*n - 0.584*n*n*n*n

    elif choice == "3":
        print("karşılıklı")
        if mk/mu > 0.4:
            print("Ast/2 formülleri için geçerlilik şartı sağlanmadı.")
        else:
            k1 = 1 + ((mk/mu) * (mk/mu))

    elif choice == "4":
        print("Ast/4 için")
        if n > 1:
            k1 = 1.12
        else:
            k1 = 1.137 + 1.233*n - 3.445*n*n + 3.083*n*n*n - 0.87*n*n*n*n
            print(k1)

    elif choice == "5":
        k1 = 1

    else:
        print("Listede olmayan bir seçeneği seçemezsiniz.")
        menu()


menu()
Astk1 = Ast * k1
print(Astk1)
```

Comment: The `k1` in your `menu()` is in a different scope.

Comment: `k1` lives in the `menu`  function. You're trying to use it outside of where it lives. You can return `k1` from the `menu` function or reconsider the design.

Comment: what is n ?  and where it is declared

Answer (score 0):

This is a scoping issue: `k1` is defined within the `menu()` function, so without any intervention, it will only be available within that function (local scope). You could define a global variable (frowned upon), or even better, have `menu()` return the value of k1. e.g.:

```
# just change the end of your function:
    else:
        print("Listede olmayan bir seçeneği seçemezsiniz.")
        k1 = menu()   # if k1 wasn't set, call menu again and use its value

    return k1         # return the value you settled on

my_k1 = menu()
Astk1 = Ast * my_k1
print(Astk1)
```

Hope that helps, Happy Coding!